# Galois group over $F_9$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory, finite-fields

I am trying to compute the Galois group of the polynomial $f(x)=x^4+2x^2-2$ over $F_3$ and $F_9$.
I see that $f(x)$ is reducible over $F_3[x]$, $f(x)=(x^2+1)^2$, therefore we have that the Galois group over $F_3$ is $\mathbb{Z}_2$.
But I have no idea about the Galois group over $F_9$.
Can someone give me some hint?

Comment: Hint: $F_9$ contains a root for $x^2+1$.

Comment: Can you explain more? I know that $F_9=F_3[x]/(x^2+1)$.

Comment: @ Dustin Levenstein $F_9$ contains a root for $ x^2-1$, then it contains all the roots, so is the Galois group the trivial group?

Comment: Because $\Bbb{F}_9$ contains both roots of $x^2+1$, it is the splitting field of $f(x)$.

Comment: @ Jyrkin Lathonen  thank you! So it implies that  the Galois group is trivial? How do we know that $F_9$ contains the roots?

Comment: @user335468 There are two ways to approach this. The more elementary approach is: Since $x^2+1$ is a quadratic, and $F_9 = F_3[x]/(x^2+1)$ is obtained by adjoining a root of this quadratic, it follows that $F_9$ contains the other root, so $F_9$ is a splitting field. The more advanced approach is: Use the fact that $x^2+1$ is an irreducible polynomial over $F_3$, and every finite extension of a finite field is automatically a splitting field.

Comment: One way to know that $\Bbb F_9$ contains the roots is to sit down with pencil and paper and do some computations in $\Bbb F_9$. These finite fields are not airy abstractions living only in the world of Platonic Ideals, they are fuzzy, furry pets that you can reach down to fondle, pick up and put in your lap, and stroke.